How were the permutations calculated in God's Playground?
I am reading God's Playground by Norman Davies and I am puzzled by this excerpt:

Given the existence of the three partitioning powers,
therefore, and of five main national movements each divided into three geographical sectors, into three main tactical groupings, and into at least three main parties, one reaches the astonishing conclusion that Polish politics at the turn of the century were faced with a total number of possible permutations of 38, or of rather more than nineteen thousand.

I understand who the three partitioning powers are, but what are the five national movements, tactical groupings, and parties he is referring to? And where does the 38 come from? Also, the total number possible permutations of 38 is way larger than 19,000.

Could you revise the title to ask a question?  In my experience, titles that ask a clear question are more likely to get high quality answer.    Could you also cite the text?  Citing the text will make it much easier for us to research and provide an answer.

The context of the book itself is enough to answer this question. It is available on archive.org for anyone curious enough to read for themselves; the relevant section is around page 76.
National Movements
The five national movements are Poles, Ukrainians, Lithuanians, Germans, and Jews:

It was common knowledge among Polish
schoolboys that Polonia, like Caesar’s Gallia, est omnis divisa
in partes tres. But not everyone was aware that the Ukrainian,
Lithuanian, German, and Jewish communities were trisected
likewise.

Here is a map of interwar Poland where you can see the locations of the relevant nationals. Keep in mind that at the time Lithuania would have been divided between Russia and Germany just like Poland; fixed borders for a restored Poland, Lithuania, or Poland-Lithuania were not yet established so it would make sense to include Germans and Lithuanians despite their relatively small area on the interwar map.

Belarusians are not listed in the "five" because the entirety of the Belarusian national movement, as Davies quotes, "could have be seated on one small sofa...a political irrelevance."
Tactical Groupings
The tactical groupings were the Nationalists, Anti-Imperialists, and Federalists discussed on earlier pages.
The Nationalists wanted to restore the Polish-Lithuanian Commonwealth and Polish domination over eastern Europe. Their aim was to unite all Polish people into one nation - and Poland was once quite large.

The Anti-Imperialists wanted a small Poland only in the exclusively Polish areas. This movement was popular with foreign supporters of an independent Poland, as Davies describes, because it allowed for example British socialists to support Poles without undermining Britain's ally Russia which controlled the lion's share of Polish lands. This would also be the case for every rump Polish state established by conquerors: the Duchy of Warsaw and the Kingdom of Poland were formed by their overlords out of land conquered from the enemy (Prussia/Austria in the first case and Russia in the second) without giving up, in the Kingdom's case, any of their "own" Poland.
The Federalists wanted to create a multi-ethnic federation. They were aware that a small Poland would not be militarily viable against neighbors hungry for another Partition, while a large imperial Poland would suffer from the instability and internal weakness that Austria-Hungary put on display. This approach ended up being very successful in Czechoslovakia (where Czechs or Slovaks alone would not make up a majority in most areas, but "Czechoslovaks" outnumbered Germans and Hungarians) but not so much in Poland.
The Intermarium project is a good illustration of what they were going for, and you can see it evolve as political realities shifted.
Political Parties
The book cites a few political parties:

Józef Piłsudski's allies
National Democrats under Roman Dmowski
Revolutionary Communists

Mathematics
You may have a poorly OCR'ed copy - it is not 38, but three to the 8th power. However, that is 6561 and not in fact 19,000. It is possible that Davies, a historian, is simply bad at math. 3 to the 9th power is 19,683 so perhaps originally there was another factor that ended up getting cut in editing without updating the figure.


There would have been more political parties, such as peasant parties, and more divisions in parties, such as the Jewish socialist parties' split between anti-Zionists in the Bund and Zionists in Poale Zion.

@Henry That's true, but I am not attempting to enumerate every single party. Merely those referred to in the book.
